# Django Choices: One of my choice items has the label copied over to the value

Tags: python, django, datetime, choicefield

Very strange issue here. I'm using the `django-choices` module (v1.3), and defined a set of choices like so:

```
class BreaktimeChoices(DjangoChoices):
    BREAKTIME_NONE = ChoiceItem(value=datetime.time(0,0), label=_('none'))
    BREAKTIME_15_MIN = ChoiceItem(value=datetime.time(0,15), label=_('15 minutes'))
    BREAKTIME_30_MIN = ChoiceItem(value=datetime.time(0,30), label=_('30 minutes'))
    BREAKTIME_45_MIN = ChoiceItem(value=datetime.time(0,45), label=_('45 minutes'))
    BREAKTIME_1_HOUR = ChoiceItem(value=datetime.time(1,0), label=_('1 hour'))
```

When I then put it into a form (with a select input) I notice that the labels are correct, but the value for BREAKTIME_NONE is 'none' (rather than the intended `00:00:00`). When printing out `BreaktimeChoices.choices` I get this:

```
((<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f995c306f50>, <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f995c306f50>), 
(datetime.time(0, 15), <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f995c310f50>),
(datetime.time(0, 30), <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f995c310bd0>),
(datetime.time(0, 45), <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f995c310ed0>),
(datetime.time(1, 0), <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f995c310fd0>))
```

As you can see, the `datetime.time(0,0)` has been changed to a `__proxy__`  object (translatable string). What's more is, the the pointer address to this proxy is the same as the `label` value for this choice. I use `DjangoChoices` all over my project and haven't had this issue before. Has anyone else seen anything like it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was fixed in a later version - upgrading `django-choices` to the latest version worked.

The issue was some code that looked like this:

```
if not self.value:
    self.value = self.label
```

...and `time(0,0)` is evaluated to `False` in that context.

Comment: Damn, was about to reply :) Anyway, here is the commit that fixed: https://github.com/bigjason/django-choices/commit/0b00f2e85db9376505503af3c3a75f0cd79e3ae7